# How can I include custom Javascript file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I have one problem. I just started using React, and I don't know how to include, or import my custom Js file.
I created custom slider (carousel) component (rfce) with custom vanila javascript included and when I run app, I got this message: **"typeError: cannot read property 'addeventlistener' of null"**.

How can I prevent it ? I know this file should load last ( if I didn't use React, I would include script.js at the bottom of the body element).

```js
const left = document.querySelector('.left');
const right = document.querySelector('.right');
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const indicatorParent = document.querySelector('.control ul'); 
const indicators = document.querySelectorAll('.control li');
var index = 0;

indicators.forEach((indicator, i) => {
  indicator.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.control .selected').classList.remove('selected');
    indicator.classList.add('selected');
    slider.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (i) * -25 + '%)';  
    index = i;
    
  });
});

  left.addEventListener('click', function() {
    index = (index > 0) ? index -1 : 0;
    document.querySelector('.control .selected').classList.remove('selected');
    indicatorParent.children[index].classList.add('selected');
    slider.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (index) * -25 + '%)';
  });

 
  right.addEventListener('click', function() {
    index = (index < 4 - 1) ? index+1 : 3;
    document.querySelector('.control .selected').classList.remove('selected');
    indicatorParent.children[index].classList.add('selected');
    slider.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (index) * -25 + '%)';
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Impossible to troubleshoot without seeing your code.

Comment: I just posted it

Comment: Post it in the question, not an answer.

Comment: can you post what the react that you do have is?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you rewriting this file with react. I assume elements with the classes left, right, slider etc. should all be applied dynamically by react, if that's the case you have to rewrite the logic with react, since `querySelector` and `addEventListener` aren't reactively updating their target if the dom changes (unlike react)

Comment: As I said, I just started using React, so I really don't know how to rewrite file in react. Anyway, thanks for help! Btw, right now I need fast solution because I don't have time to learn react step by step, tomorow I need to send code to my possible employer.